# Formateo de bloques de código HTML/CSS/JavaScript largos

Tags: soporte, ediciones, formato, stack-snippets

Estaba respondiendo una pregunta y tuve que insertar un snippet de código un poco largo y me preguntaba ya que desconozco si hay alguna forma de hacer que se pueda colapsar ese bloque por defecto para que luego cada  lector, si así lo desea pueda desplegarlo.

[Esta es la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/9440/225)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay un botón (o checkbox) que hace eso... justamente eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: excelente! por apurado se me pasó.